# why does the Iterator Yield A Different Value?

Tags: setq, iteration, generators

I tested two similar *generator*s, and the result confused me.

1. This iterator yields values as I expected:

   ```lisp
   ELISP> (iter-defun f (x)
            (setq x (iter-yield (1+  x)))
            (setq x (iter-yield (* 2 x))))
   f
   ELISP> (progn
            (setq x (f 1))
            `(,(iter-next x) ,(iter-next x 3)))
   (2 6)
   ```
2. But this one yields a different value:

   ```lisp
   ELISP> (iter-defun g (x)
            (setq x (iter-yield (1+  x))
                  x (iter-yield (* 2 x))))
   g
   ELISP> (progn
            (setq x (g 1))
            `(,(iter-next x) ,(iter-next x 3)))
   (2 2)
   ```

The above two *generator*s are very similar,
but why are the values yielded by their *iterator*s different?

Comment: I haven't tested to make sure, but my assumption is that in the sequential assignments in the first generator, the x on the RHS of the second assignment is the result of the first assignment, whereas in the second generator the x on the RHS of both assignments is the value of the argument.

Comment: @NickD: Is it a bug?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't even know if my assumption is correct: I stil have not tried it out.

Comment: In Emacs 29, the examples yield the same values. Indeed, in Emacs 28 the yielded values are different, like in your question.

Comment: @dalanicolai: Oh sorry, I forgot to say my Emacs version and machine environment. Yes, my Emacs is v28.2 and the system-configure is x86_64-w64-mingw32.

Comment: Ah well, we're not reporting bugs here (where this should be mentioned, which happens automatically if you use `M-x report-emacs-bug). I would also not have expected this. Just I noticed that the behavior was different here on version 29, so then I checked on 28.

Comment: Possibly annoying comment: this is an example of why seasoned coders *never* reassign. The recommended rule is: treat each variable as read-only after initial assignment. For best safety, always do that single initial assignment immediately on introducing the variable. You automatically prevent a whole class of bugs thereby.

Comment: @PhilHudson: Reasonable, but not annoying to me because we are talking about different topics here. Your suggestion is about coding conventions; my question is about the inconsistency between doc and actual behaviors. As a novice, when encountering a potential “document bug”, instead of seeing it as a bug, I first wonder if I'm misinterpreting the doc or actual behavior of `setq` or `generator.el`. This inconsistency will make new Emacs users find it hard to study Elisp through the manual, so I post this question. (The way I learned the language is to write some code and watch how they behave.

Comment: @Shynur: Quite right. In this case the reassignment is key to illustrating the point you're bringing up. I shouldn't have mentioned the coding technique consideration. In this context it's a distraction.